# why is this json c#-Object serialized wrong

Tags: c#, json

Im new to json and c# and need help in the right direction.
Look at the picture down below and you see the json string looking funny with slashes.

How can i remove the slashes or what parser should i use if this is wrong

This is my C# code:

```
 PostList p = new PostList();

 Posts posts1 = new Posts();
 posts1.username = "aaaa";
 posts1.message = "hej again";
 posts1.time = "time1";
 p.setPost(posts1);

 Posts posts2 = new Posts();
 posts2.username = "bbbb";
 posts2.message = "hej again again";
 posts2.time = "time2";
 p.setPost(posts2);

 Posts posts3 = new Posts();
 posts3.username = "cccc";
 posts3.message = "hej again again agin";
 posts3.time = "time3";
 p.setPost(posts3);
 System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(p.GetType());
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 serializer.WriteObject(ms, p);
 string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

This is my class that i try to serialize

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace Project2
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PostList
    {
        [DataMember]
        private List<Posts> posts { get; set; } 

        public PostList(){

            this.posts = new List<Posts>();
        }


        public List<Posts> getPostContainterList()
        {
            return posts;
        }

        public void setPost(Posts post)
        {
            posts.Add(post);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Posts
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String message { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String time { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE SHOWING WHERE STRING COME FROM**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to your `PostList` class?

Comment: What are you using to view the JSON? Have "plain text" available? (e.g. what does it shown when inspecting the result with a debugger?) I would guess *something else* later on has added those...

Comment: Those slashes are not actually inserted there.. the IDE is showing you the escaped string.. :/

Comment: @Baz1nga Then what's up with the red box? :p~

Comment: write the content to a file to verify if those slashes are there or not..

Comment: when i add the [Serializable] attribute the output looks like this {\"<posts>k__BackingField\":[{\"message\":\".......

Comment: The "red box" come from ...http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit your service with something like Fiddler / Chrome tools / IE f12 developer tools to see the *raw* response. I suspect that your JSON is actually fine, and that the slashes are added by the JSON viewer you use.

If ur new to JSON,a great quick resource for pasting in long JSON strings and seeing them hierarchically is [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) . It validates them too.

Comment: about where the slashes are coming from i updated my question with a new pictures showing a debug session when the parser spits out the serialized string with slashes. The serialized string has slashed straight from the beginning. Thanks for jsonlint.com